# Get HID Keyboard Device Using Raw Input from C# in Windows 8

Tags: c#, barcode-scanner

I read article [Using Raw Input from C# to handle multiple keyboards](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard) and download the [source](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/rawinput/rawinput_src.zip). It works when I run it in Windows 7, but failed when I run it in Windows 8.

I've got **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."** error on

```
string deviceClass = (string)OurKey.GetValue("Class");
if (deviceClass.ToUpper().Equals("KEYBOARD"))
```

I placed breakpoint at `string deviceClass` and see the value is null. If you look at the downloaded source the value is obtained from the registry. Is there any difference between Windows 7 and Windows 8 to obtain this value? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

That code expects a `Class` value to be present in the appropriate `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\HID\` key, on my Windows 8 machine none of the entries have this key so you will get the behaviour you describe.

That is a poor way to get the class even if the key did exist; instead p/invoke `GetRawInputDeviceInfo()` for the device class.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'll look for `GetRawInputDeviceInfo`

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the **Class** REG_SZ value no longer used in Windows 8 and higher.

You can use the **Service** value instead but make sure to search for the appropriate data **kbdhid**

```
string deviceClass = (string)OurKey.GetValue("Service");
if (deviceClass.Equals("kbdhid"))
```